# Which web framework is used by sites like Producteev and Trello?

Tags: web-frameworks

I see quite a few web applications which have a very similar layout, so I assume there is a particular framework they're using in common. The top bar has this sort of layout:

[image]
[image]

And there's a side-bar, which is often a bit Apple-esque:

[image]

Does anyone know if this is some kind of common (hopefully open-source) UI framework?

Comment: Hope this might help http://blog.fogcreek.com/the-trello-tech-stack/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The outward appearance of a web application is never an indication of which framework was used to build it.  The things you're showing are all the results of styling and can be done with any web framework.

You can, however, look at the source to see what kind of javascript references there are and get an idea that way.  Certain frameworks will sometimes give clues (asp.net will have _viewstate, etc.).

For example, in looking at the source for Trello you cain find a js reference that has a comment header section that gives you lots of clues:

```
/*

Sizzle CSS Selector Engine
Copyright 2011, The Dojo Foundation
Released under the MIT, BSD, and GPL Licenses.
More information: http://sizzlejs.com/

jQuery JavaScript Library v1.7.2
http://jquery.com/

Copyright 2011, John Resig
Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
http://jquery.org/license

Includes Sizzle.js
http://sizzlejs.com/
Copyright 2011, The Dojo Foundation
Released under the MIT, BSD, and GPL Licenses.

Date: Wed Mar 21 12:46:34 2012 -0700

jQuery UI 1.8.14

Copyright 2011, AUTHORS.txt (http://jqueryui.com/about)
Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
http://jquery.org/license

http://docs.jquery.com/UI

jQuery UI Widget 1.8.14

Copyright 2011, AUTHORS.txt (http://jqueryui.com/about)
Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
http://jquery.org/license

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Widget

jQuery UI Mouse 1.8.14

Copyright 2011, AUTHORS.txt (http://jqueryui.com/about)
Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
http://jquery.org/license

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Mouse

Depends:
jquery.ui.widget.js
: Licensed under The MIT License. See license.txt and http://www.datejs.com/license/. 
@website: http://www.datejs.com/

This application uses other third-party javascript components
distributed under appropriate licenses. For more information,
see the following files at http://trello.com/js/lib/
backbone.js
highcharts.js
json2.js
markdown.js
socket.io.js
underscore.js
Socket.IO.js build:0.8.6, development. Copyright(c) 2011 LearnBoost <dev@learnboost.com> MIT Licensed 
! CHANGES FOR TRELLO: Remove all transports other than built-in browser Websockets,     try/catch around errors, fix transport merge, fix heartbeat
! Diff with published v0.8.6 for the details.
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it so thoroughly!